# Implementing a "X bytes downloaded from Y"

Tags: java, android, networking

today I'm trying to implement a file download, with a notification about how many bytes are downloaded already (Like "1Mb of 150Mb downloaded"). However, I'm stuck in some maths.

```
class DescarregarFitxer extends AsyncTask<String,String,String>{
    final String rutaDesti;
    final String urlOrigen;
    URLConnection urlConnect;
    View v;
    byte[] buffer = new byte[8 * 1024];

    public DescarregarFitxer(String rutaDesti, String urlOrigen, View v){
        this.rutaDesti = rutaDesti;
        this.urlOrigen = urlOrigen;
        this.v = v;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();

    }

    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        try{
            int size = 0;
            int counter = 0;
            URL url = new URL(urlOrigen);
            urlConnect = url.openConnection();
            size = urlConnect.getContentLength();
            productView.this.callBackDownload(v, "{'action':'start','size':'"+size+"'}");
            InputStream input = urlConnect.getInputStream();
            try {
                OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(rutaDesti);
                try {
                    int bytesRead;
                    while ((bytesRead = input.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                        output.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                        counter+=buffer.length;
                        productView.this.callBackDownload(v, "{'action':'update','size':'"+size+"','counter':'"+counter+"'}");
                    }
                } finally {
                    output.close();
                }
            } finally {
                input.close();
            }
        } catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        productView.this.callBackDownload(v, "{'action':'done'}");
    }
}
```

As you can see in the above code, several things must be noted:

- As soon as download starts, I get the lenght of the file to be downloaded.
- Every loop on the while, I've a callback to update a TextView with the size downloaded.

I've everything I need, but I am not sure what do now.

Example:

- File size: 9383138 bytes
- Every Loop: 8192 bytes

However, I did this in the callback:

```
Log.d("debugging","we downloaded: "+counter+" of "+size);
```

And when it ends, it says:

> we downloaded : 26206208 of 9383138

As you can see, some of my calculations are wrong. Maybe I'm doing maths with different kind of units.

Can you help me?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding up bytesRead instead of buffer.length.

Answer (score 1):

```
counter+=buffer.length;
```

That's not the amount of bytes downloaded

```
counter+=bytesRead;
```

Is. Just like you write `bytesRead` bytes to your file

Comment: You both were right. Now it is working correctly. However Gil Moshayof gave the answer 30 seconds earlier!

Answer (score 1):

For a very large download, you should not use an AsynTask. They have not been designed for this : https://stackoverflow.com/a/13082084/693752

You got 2 solutions :

- use the [native download manger of Android](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DownloadManager.html), for your needs, that should be a super fit
- use a library with a good handling. Have a look at [RoboSpice github's repo](https://github.com/octo-online/robospice/blob/release/README.md). If you don't like it, you can find alternative libraries at the bottom of the page.

Comment: That question states some issues which I already control (when activity is destroyed, I cancel the AsyncTask). For now I'll keep using it if it doesn't make any troubles. As soon as I've any, I will remember this and will go for a better approach. Thanks for the advice!!

Answer (score 0):

use bytesRead to be increament with counter

```
counter += bytesRead;
```