# Is Asynctask safe to use large downloads rather than thread?

Tags: java, android, multithreading, android-asynctask

Most people using asynctask for long running operations instead of thread.

But the documentation says that:

> AsyncTask is designed to be a helper class around Thread and Handler
>   and does not constitute a generic threading framework. AsyncTasks
>   should ideally be used for short operations (a few seconds at the
>   most.) If you need to keep threads running for long periods of time,
>   it is highly recommended you use the various APIs provided by the
>   java.util.concurrent package such as Executor, ThreadPoolExecutor and
>   FutureTask.

My question is if ui updation is not a concern, what is the problem I should face when I use asynctask for long running background operations?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12797550/android-asynctask-for-long-running-operations

Comment: use handler for heavy/large downloads and not asynctask.

Comment: for downloading files I prefer using `IntentService`..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AsyncTask is tied to the lifecycle of the activity, so it's very easy to mess its state in configuration changes / other events.

Personally, I recommend you to use HTTP libraries, like [Ion](https://github.com/koush/ion) or similar. It's easy to use, and gives you out-of-the-box progress control.

Answer (score 0):

For downloading large amount of files or executing many asynchronous and time consuming operations in Android application, I would use the following elements:

- [Service](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html) as a long running operation
- [Android Priority Job Queue](https://github.com/path/android-priority-jobqueue) running inside mentioned Service and executing queue of tasks

Moreover, Android 5 has built-in so called [JobScheduler](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/job/JobScheduler.html), which does similar thing as Android Priority Job Queue, but if you want to supprot *pre-Lollipop* devices, you should choose first solution.

If you have single task and you don't need queue of tasks, you can use RxJava inside Service instead of Android Priority Job Queue.

Comment: NOTE: you can't use just Service for a long operations. You should start background thread inside it, otherwise Service will be invoked in the main/ui thread and will lock UI. http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html

Comment: Yes, you are right. I've written that we should use Android Priority Job Queue or RxJava inside Service. These libraries are capable to execute time consuming operations in a separate thread. Service is long running operation and it doesn't depend on Activity lifecycle, but it's not executed in a separate thread.