# Why should not use asynctasks for long running operations

Tags: android

Why shouldn't we use AsyncTasks for long running operations?

Why they recommend to use services for long running operations?

Comment: this has been answered here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12797550/android-asynctask-for-long-running-operations