# How not to make a ReactJS app freeze when a huge number of docs arrive from a Firestore snapshot?

Tags: reactjs, google-cloud-firestore, listener, snapshot

I've a ReactJS application made up of 3 simple elements: 2 numbers and an input text. This is a test page of course.
The 2 numbers refers to the number of elements that are present in 2 separate Firestore collections, and the input text doesn't do anything.
The goal of my experiment is to understand why if I write a huge amount of docs in a short time in the collections (I'm using [k6](https://k6.io) in order to) and just print those two numbers by listening to Firestore snapshots, my page completely freezes until all the messages have arrived.

Here is my code

```
const App = () => {
  const [col1, setCol1] = useState(0);
  const [col2, setCol2] = useState(0);
  const [value, setValue] = useState('');
  useEffect(() => {
    console.debug('*** EFFECT');

    db
      .collection('abcd/efgh/collection1')
      .orderBy('timestamp')
      .startAt(new Date())
      .limitToLast(1)
      .onSnapshot(({ docs }) => {
        setCol1((e) => e + 1);
      });

    db
      .collection('qwer/tyui/collection2')
      .orderBy('timestamp')
      .onSnapshot(({ docs }) => {
        console.debug('***', docs.length);
        setCol2(docs.length);
      });
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
      {exist}

      <br />

      {messages}

      <br />

      <Input onChange={({ target: { value } }) => setValue(value)} value={value} />
    </>
  );
};
```

Of course the final target is to understand how to not cause the freeze.
From [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45317425/firebase-listener-freezes-app-ui) I see that spawning a separate thread will help, so the equivalent in JS desktop are WebWorkers.
Could that be a right idea?
Do you have any other suggestion?

Comment: Posted an answer is it helpful?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

I had basically the exact same issue, so I spent a bunch of time testing this myself, and here's what I found.

**Debouncing State Updates:** *Helps a little*.

Basically, if you're constantly re-rendering large amounts of data, you can use a lot of memory and/or drop frames, so I assumed that debouncing the function would help.

It did help a *bit* but the app would still freeze or crash if more than a few hundred rows were updated.

Here's how I implemented:

```
const debounce = (func, wait) => {
    let timeout;

    return function executedFunction(...args) {
        const later = () => {
            clearTimeout(timeout);
            func(...args);
        };

        clearTimeout(timeout);
        timeout = setTimeout(later, wait);
    };
};
```

...

```
    const debouncedSetItems = useMemo(() =>
        debounce((newItems) => {
            setCol1(newItems);
        }, 5000), []
    );
```

...

```
    useEffect(() => {
        const unsubscribe = firestore.collection("myCollection").onSnapshot((querySnapshot) => {
            const newItems = [];
            querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
                newItems.push({
                    id: doc.id,
                    ...doc.data()
                });
            });
    
            debouncedSetItems(newItems);

        });
 }, [debouncedSetItems]);
```

**Slowing the Write Speed**: *Helps a lot; has limitations.*

Essentially, if you can pause every once in a while when writing large amounts of data, the app won't hang.

I was doing large numbers of writes via a cloud function, so what I did was pause for a few seconds every 50 writes:

```
async function sleep(milliseconds) {
    return new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, milliseconds));
}
```

...

```
if (i > 0 && i % 50 === 0) {
    console.log("Sleeping for 5 seconds");
    await sleep(5000);
}
```

This totally fixed the issue, but it has the obvious limitation of slowing your writes down, which may or may not be an issue. For me, it wasn't a huge deal because I still had plenty of buffer leftover in the 9-minute cloud function runtime limit, but your mileage may vary.

Curious to see how others have solved this.