# Could this Asynctask cause OutOfMemory on Android?

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

I often use `AsyncTask` because
`AsyncTask` is have ThreadPool,

so Even if the thread grows indefinitely, Memory is managed to avoid stress.

but, recently occur `OutOfMemoryError: pthread_create (1040KB stack) failed: Try again`

so, I found the suspicious part.

```
public static class getPubIpAddress extends AsyncTask<Void, Void ,String> {

      @Override
      protected void onPreExecute() {
         super.onPreExecute(); 
      }

      @Override
      protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
          try {
              URL pubIp = new URL("https://myserver.co.kr/ipaddr.php");
              BufferedReader in = BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                       pubIp.openStream()));
              String pub = in.readLine();
          } catch (Exception e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
          }
          return pub;
       }
       @Override
       protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
          super.onPostExecute(result);
       }
}
```

this asynctask get public ip.
and execute when network connect, change network.

could this asynctask cause outofmemory on android?

thanks:)

Comment: It will not give you out of memory.

Comment: Try this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10515023/outofmemory-on-asynctask-in-android/24841939

Comment: have you check that your asyncTask run again when you change network.?

Comment: @SardarKhan  yes run again, when I change wifi ap , run again

Comment: check my answer and try ..

Comment: You should close the BufferedReader once done with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem might be asynctask is running again and again . You have to check for asyncTask finished then try to reRun it.
Check this post.
[Android, AsyncTask, check status?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7588584/android-asynctask-check-status)

Second Approach you can set a flag in at Application Level for check that if the AsyncTask is running then donot start again the AsyncTask if running if not then start your AsnckTask.

At Application level class put this varaible

```
public static boolean alreadyRuning = false;
```

and also this getter and setter

```
 public static boolean isRunning() {
    return alreadyRuning;
}

public static void setRunning(boolean alreadyRunning) {
    this.alreadyRuning= alreadyRunning;
}
```

or you can close the Buffer When done.

```
BufferedReader in = BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
            pubIp.openStream()));
    try {
            String pub = in.readLine();
    } finally {
        in.close();
    }
```